# getting input text value based on data attribute using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to extract the value of the text based on its data attribute.

**HTML:**

```
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="CardName" data-id="CardName">
```

My Jquery

```
 var cardN = $('input[data-id="CardName"]').val();
```

Comment: This is not working?

Comment: is this a demo?

Comment: use $('input[data-integrapay=CardName]').val();

Comment: @danishfarhaj I think the quotes shouldn't be a problem... the code should work

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: yeah you are right. it's working. http://fiddle.jshell.net/UYMxa/282/

Comment: Yep works https://jsfiddle.net/1431e391/1/ may be he's not calling the function in document.ready

Answer (score 2):

Remove double qutation in data-id:

```js
$('.btn').click(function(){
   var cardN = $('input[data-id=CardName]').val();
   alert(cardN)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="CardName" data-id="CardName" >
<input class="btn" type="button" value="click" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this ,

**HTML CODE**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="CardName" value="Hello" data-pay="CardName">
```

**JQuery**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 var cardN = $('input[data-id="CardName"]').val();
 alert(cardN);
 });
```

The value in the Text box will be shown as alertmsg.You must be written query function within document ready.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you:

```
var cardN = getVal("CardName");
function getVal(name){
   return $('input[data-id="' + name + '"]').val();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you want.

```
 $(function(){
  var cardN = $("input[data-integrapay='CardName']").val();
  alert(cardN);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var cardN = $('input[data-id="CardName"]').attr('value');
  alert(cardN);
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var cardN = $('input[data-id="CardName"]').val();
  alert(cardN);
});
```